# ODE $ y''-3y'+2y=4(2-a)e^{-ax}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

I have to solve the system

$y'=-y-2z+2e^{-ax}$,

$z'=3y+4z+e^{-ax}$.

I expressed z from the first equation and plugged it into the second equation. The result is equation $y''-3y'+2y=4(2-a)e^{-ax}$. How to solve this equation?

Any help is welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Aryadeva So I get $(y+z)'=2(y+z)+3e^{-ax}$ and $((y+z)e^{-2x})'=3e^{-(a+2)x}$, from where I can deduce expression for y+z. And what then? Also, I would like to solve the equation $y''-3y'+2y=4(2-a)e^{-ax}$.

Comment: You have $y$ as a function of $z$ plug this in one of the DE and eliminate one unknown then you have a first DE in $y$ or $z$ ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$y''-3y'+2y=4(2-a)e^{-ax}$$
Solve the homogeneous part first:
$$y''-3y'+2y=0$$
Polynomial characteristic is
$$r^2-3r+2=(r-1)(r-2)=0 $$
$$ \implies S_r=\{1,2\}$$
$$y_h=c_1e^x+c_2e^{2x}$$
For the particular solution it depends on $a$ if $a \ne -1,-2$ try the particular solution:
$$y_p=Ae^{-ax}$$
$a$ if $a = -1$ or $a=-2$ try the particular solution:
$$y_p=Axe^{-ax}$$
Plug this in the original inhomogeneous DE and find the constant A then the solution is
$$y=y_h+y_p$$

---

You can add both DE and solve a first order DE instead
$$(y+z)'=2(y+z)+3e^{-ax}$$
$$((y+z)e^{-2x})'=3e^{-(a+2)x}$$
This is easy to solve.
$$y=-z +3e^{2x}\int e^{-(a+2)x}dx$$
The integral depends on the value of a you have to discuss ($a \ne -2$ or $a=-2$). Plug y in this DE
$$z'=3y+4z+e^{-ax}$$
Then you have a first DE in $z$ that's easy to integrate.

Answer (score 1):

**hint**

To make it easy, put

$$y=Ye^{-ax}$$
$$y'=(Y'-aY)e^{-ax}$$
$$y''=(Y''-2aY'+a^2Y)e^{-ax}$$

Your last equation becomes

$$Y''-2aY'+a^2Y-3Y'+3aY+2Y=4(2-a)$$
or
$$Y''-(2a+3)Y'+(a^2+3a+2)Y=4(2-a)$$

The discriminant is
$$(2a+3)^2-4(a^2+3a+2)=1$$
A particular constant solution is
$$Y_p=\frac{4(2-a)}{(a+1)(a+2)}$$
Thus
$$Y=Ae^{(a+1)x}+Be^{(a+2)x}+Y_p$$
and
$$y=Ae^x+Be^{2x}+\frac{4(2-a)}{(a+1)(a+2)}e^{-ax}$$
For $a\ne -1,-2$.